# MYSQL: Updating a column based on select statement with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've got a select statement that returns a list of all items in a document store that have comments (stored in a separate comments table).

What I'm trying to do is to update the value of another column in public_document_store (skin_id) for all the documents that have released comments, based on the statement below.

This returns the records I want to update:

```
SELECT public_document_store_talkback.document_id,
public_document_store.section_id
FROM public_document_store
INNER JOIN public_document_store_talkback ON public_document_store_talkback.document_id = public_document_store.document_id
WHERE public_document_store_talkback.is_released = 1 
AND public_document_store_talkback.is_rejected = 0 
AND public_document_store.section_id = 10;
```

I've tried to update the skin_id field like this:

```
Update public_document_store SET skin_id = 6 
WHERE document_id IN (Select... [as per the statement above] )
```

But this returns an error:

> [Err] 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

I've tried various other permutations based on other answers here, but without any luck (My knowledge of SQL is pretty basic, so apologies if I am missing something obvious here)

Any ideas how I can make this work would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SELECT` query needs only a little modification to convert it into an `UPDATE` statement,

```
UPDATE  public_document_store a
        INNER JOIN public_document_store_talkback b
            ON b.document_id = a.document_id
SET     a.skin_id = 6
WHERE   b.is_released = 1 AND 
        b.is_rejected = 0 AND 
        a.section_id = 10
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks very much. I clearly need to work on improving my syntax...